# issue with Userfrosting & Composer - no matching packages

Tags: composer-php, userfrosting

Just working my way through the Userfrosting 4 tutorial.  The basic app is up and running and am now creating the first sprinkle under "Your First UserFrosting Site".

On running composer update I get the following:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
- userfrosting/config dev-master requires userfrosting/support ^4.0.0 -> no matching package found.
- userfrosting/config dev-master requires userfrosting/support ^4.0.0 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for userfrosting/config dev-master -> satisfiable by userfrosting/config[dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

I've replaced my code with the copied / pasted code from the tutorial and still get the errors. I've absolutely no idea where to go from here - any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version (4.0.11-alpha as of now) since the component versioning was changed/fixed in a recent version.

The core `composer.json` file shoudn't use the `dev-master` version of `userfrosting/config` component anymore, but one of the `4.0.x` version. See : https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/app/sprinkles/core/composer.json#L31. If you have a custom ^composer.json` file in your sprinkle, you don't need to add the packages define in the core composer file again.

That being said, if you're still having some issues, you can try running `composer clear-cache` as composer might have cached some outdated info.

Comment: Thanks Louis.  Excuse my ignorance, but what is the best / recommended way to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: If you cloned the git repo, it's just a matter of pulling the newest changes. You can also comes on the [chat](http://chat.userfrosting.com/) for more assistance.